# Passing data to the data layer

Tags: c#, mvvm

My model consists of a single main object that the user can add various other objects too. The added objects are stored in `List<object>` contained within the main object and it's associated child objects.

So if the project is a house. The user can add a number of `Room` objects to the house which are stored in `List<Room> RoomList`. Then each `Room` can have a number of `Furnishings` added again stored in each Room `List<Furnishing> FurnishingsList`

The question is how to implement this in the MVVM approach? When the user adds a new object do i add it to the `ObservableCollection` in the ViewModel so the view is updated and at the same time add it to the model which is hooked into the VM? Or do i store it in the VM until a save or commit commmand and then pass it to the Model?

In my example i have various editors (each is a user control). So the user can edit the house at a high level, using one editor to add, edit and remove rooms from the house. And, at a lower level, using a different editor to edit each room, adding and removing `Furnishings`.

So when the user 'Edits' a room say. I produce an `EditRoomModelView` containing said `Room`. The user adds, edits and otherwise manipulates the furnishings in that room.

At each command is it best to sync the data in the Model and the ModelViee as above. Or do i shove the changes straight into the Model and have the ViewModel provide only getters on the injected Model properties. This way however adding objects to the Model Lists does not update the view. i would really have to add the data to both the ModelView and the Model at the same time so everything is at the same state.

Appologies for rambling, struggling to find a nice approach to this, anyone uderstand what i'm getting at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a single, good answer.  It sounds as though you're debating as to how to maintain coherence - do you have a simple pass-through scheme from the presentation layer, or do you interpose on user requests and have logic in there.

If that is, in fact, the question, there are various factors at play.  Do you prefer to do validation in the presentation layer?  How complex is the application and how scaleable does it need to be?  Do your view models need to be accessed in multiple places?

So, with all that in mind, I can tell you how I personally prefer approaching this problem (specifically, the issue of adding that you mention).  I typically like to create view models that describe user concerns with generics such as `EditItemViewModel<T>` or `ListViewModel<T>`.  So, in the GUI, there would be some kind of listbox of rooms bound to a `ListViewModel<Room>`.  This VM would obviously expose an observable collection, but also commands for Add, Delete, Edit.

So, from my perspective, the presentation layer, view-modelly stuff that this VM is going to do is route requests for other GUI concerns.  If you click "Add" to add a room, this VM is responsible for initiating a request, via a command, for whatever screen/window/whatever is necessary for room adding, which will have its own VM.  This VM, upon receiving an add request, will pass the generated data transfer object down to the domain where validation will occur and whatever domain operations are necessary.  I usually handle this via a service layer.  Now, if the domain operation was successful, the service layer will raise some kind of even or callback to let the list VM know that there is a change.  When that happens, the list VM re-queries its service and updates its observable collection accordingly.  Now, your GUI is consistent with the domain across the board.

The reason I favor this type of layered approach is that all of the business logic occurs in  a place 'below' the GUI, and the GUI need not concern itself with this occurrence.  Conceptually, GUI just says "here, domain layer, user wants to add this - do all that, and let any interested GUI components know when you're done so that they can refresh themselves".

What I'm describing here will naturally incur some overhead as compared to a simple, pass-through scheme or a scheme in which the VMs just re-expose properties on some model object.  But, personally, I think the advantage gained from a decoupling perspective is worth it, especially as you scale up the application.  It gives you the ability to fundamentally alter the domain model's internal interactions without changing the presentation layer code a lick.

Comment: Thanks Erik, When i pass the new object down to the domain layer successfully and it is stored in the `List<object>` how can i refresh the VM's ObservableCollection which represents the `List<object>`? Does the service layer re-instantiate the ObservableCollection to reflect the changes?

Comment: I wouldn't have anything below the presentation layer even know what ObservableCollection is (i.e. no reference to the WPF assembly that contains it).  The way I usually have GUI components notified about this is using events or callbacks.  For a simple example, consider two VMs with reference to the same service instance.  VM A tells the service to add a Room, and the service does whatever magic is necessary to add a room.  When it's finished and successful, it raises an event that VM B listens to.  When the event is raised, VM B re-queries the service for all rooms...

Comment: In actual implementation, the domain itself would handle the adding and then raise an event, which the service would consume and relay to the VM.  But the idea here is this - VMs just know how to ask the service for objects (POCO/DTO) and how to pass them for operations like update.  So, the relationship between service and VM is that the VM will request objects (Get/GetAll) and request operations (Add, Edit, etc).  The VM will also listen to a service event, call it "OnDirty", that tells the VM when it might be out of sync with the domain.  The VM then has the burden of re-querying.

Answer (score 2):

First: `View` is a mirror of your `DataModel`, so **always** add *first* to the `Model` and only after think if it push on `Vm` or on `View`.

Second: `ViewModel` is a bridge that connects your `Model` with `View`, but doesn't mean that it has to be structured in a same way `Model` was made. If you want to show to the user all child collections, you have to expose them like a properties and construct their `parent-child` relationship internaly in `VM` or in `VM` have just "raw" collections and have effective relationship between them in `DataModel`.

Comment: I disagree with the statement "always add first to the Model and only after think if it push on Vm or on View", there is nothing wrong with view models creating other view model instances, e.g an OrderViewModel creating new OrderLineViewModel instances.

Comment: @ColinE: if the use adds a new object, imo, it's unacceptable that it finishes on `UI` level. Waiting for what? This is not  `web development` were we keep sometimes the data on `Ui level` to make a validation, agregation... as data trasmition is costy, but here in `deskto world` don't see any reason why in any moment of my application lifetime I can not ask a `model` about a current state and do not have a valid responce.

Answer (score 2):

From the application you describe it sounds like your view-model layer does not modify or shape your model significantly. So, I would make the various view-model property setters / getters simple adapters on the wrapped model objects. That way your model will be updated immediately when the view model changes.

However ... if you need to provide 'cancel' functionality, i.e. the user opens a modal form for editing some view model, but then cancels rather than OK's the edit, this simple approach will not work.

The timing of when you commit to the model layer rarely makes much difference because this is typically not a time consuming process. What is more significant is when the model state is persisted. This is often triggered by the explicit invocation of a save command which send the model to a persistence service (file / cloud etc ...)